# Jquery - remove end of string if string starts with... Multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Thanks for reading this, im a complete noob to javascript / jquery and dont really know where to start with this one!

I have a label on a webpage, sometimes many labels, where i would like to remove any text after a specified variable.

For example i may have

```
<label for="pa_jc005-chest">Chest Size - JC005</label>
<label for="pa_rg085-chest">Chest Size - RG085</label>
<label for="pa_tf005-chest">Chest Size - TF005</label>
<label for="pa_tfd05-chest">Waist Size - TFd05</label>
<label for="pa_3fd06-chest">Inside Leg - 3Fd056</label>
```

But i only want to display the following like

```
Chest Size
Chest Size
Chest Size
Waist Size
Inside Leg
```

The best way i see this problem working out is to manually specify what i would like to end up with eg 'Chest Size' and have the javascript remove anything after the matched string.

Ive spend the last few hours reading and reading and i have found various ways to edit a string but nothing quite like what i need.

Any help / advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `var str1 = "Chest Size - JC005";
alert(str1.split("-")[0]);`

Comment: You can't have done very good searching. You can use a regular expression, you can use `indexOf`, you can use `split()`. Please show what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I’m sorry if my searching abilities aren’t sufficient enough to find the solution. Like I mentioned in my first post I did not know where to start and after a few hours of getting nowhere with google I’ve have sought help here. As for no code, I don’t have any that remotely works other than crash my page and with all the different attempts you would have a page as long as your arm to read through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, all texts have a '-', you need to split the '-' and get all text you have before this, see the example

```js
$('label').each(function(i, label) {
 var text = $(label).text().split("-")[0];
 $(label).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="pa_jc005-chest">Chest Size - JC005</label>
<label for="pa_rg085-chest">Chest Size - RG085</label>
<label for="pa_tf005-chest">Chest Size - TF005</label>
<label for="pa_tfd05-chest">Waist Size - TFd05</label>
<label for="pa_3fd06-chest">Inside Leg - 3Fd056</label>
```

Comment: This works a treat @Jorge Hess Thank you very much for your help on this. ive also amended label to "th" on another page to amend the same item. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just the given text from the whole HTML then you can do this:

```
var html = `<label for="pa_jc005-chest">Chest Size - JC005</label>
    <label for="pa_rg085-chest">Chest Size - RG085</label>
    <label for="pa_tf005-chest">Chest Size - TF005</label>
    <label for="pa_tfd05-chest">Waist Size - TFd05</label>
    <label for="pa_3fd06-chest">Inside Leg - 3Fd056</label>`;

var cleaned = html.replace(/.+["']>(.+) \- .*(\n|$)/gi, '$1$2');
```

Much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks @Azamantes Im not sure i understand this code correct but am i right in thinking this will only work for the options given?

Comment: It will work for everything you put after `something'>` or `something">` and before ` - something`

Comment: Ive got the other answer working at the moment. will have a look into this when i get chance, looks like more going on so not sure which is more efficient?

Comment: I edited my answer. No loops, just 1 simple RegExp replace and you get exactly what you need.